# html-email button design shape with buttons.cm as template?

Tags: button, html-email

There's a 'roundrect' as a parameter, are there other parameters?
Is it possible to make a button with 5 corners?

Is it possible to make a romb? How do I change the 4 corner positions?

Or is it a limit due to 'guaranteed to work' with mso render engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`roundrect` referes to [VML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb229519(v=vs.85).aspx), which Outlook 2007/10/13/16 can use to render elements emails. In looking at [VML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb263897(v=vs.85).aspx) [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb229530(v=vs.85).aspx), there doesn't seem to be a way to manipulate individual points. It's also fairly involved to draw [shapes in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) (for email clients that support this level of CSS).

Without knowing what kind of button you're building, sounds like **using an image (background *or* foreground) for the shape might be your best bet**. All email clients render images pretty consistently. If you use a [background image](https://backgrounds.cm/) allows you to use HTML for the button text.

Comment: So while trying to stay 'safe' within the suggested buttons.cm structure; it's **not possible** to change the shape w/out using images, but those are not guaranteed to load in html-emails.

Comment: Correct, buttons.cm can make *rectangles* using VML, I don't know of a reliable way to change the shape. Images are well supported, but don't always load automatically.

Answer (score 1):

one of my clients wanted a 6-cornered button, like a hexagon. To achieve this I just made a square button and applied a background-png in a shape of a hexagon to it. This worked perfect in all tested mail clients. I think with just html and css it would be much too difficult and I pretty sure most clients would make lots of trouble.